# PHP-FPM, chroot, Ubuntu Precise 12.04, and no access to DNS

Tags: ubuntu, chroot

There's a plenty of advices across the Internet on how to enable DNS in chroot.

The problem is that there's no `/lib/libnss*` files in the Ubuntu Precise.

I've tried to copy these files from `/etc/`: `hosts`, `nsswitch.conf`, `resolv.conf` and the entire `/lib` directory. But DNS is still not working.

Does anyone have a recipe for the recent Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

well... there are two solutions: the first, and most simple one, is to look for the library into `/lib64` if present, or eventually using `locate libnss` to look for it.
The other solution would be to use `strace` to see where is the system looking for the library and look in the main system for those libraries. :)

Answer (score 0):

As a start, this script, once customized, should give you a basis for a chroot.

http://www.fuschlberger.net/programs/ssh-scp-sftp-chroot-jail/make_chroot_jail.sh

Just as a caveat for other readers, just read this

[PHP-FPM chroot with chdir](https://serverfault.com/questions/430400/php-fpm-chroot-with-chdir/430406#comment461162_430406)